# Java JDBC about Blob and Clob, need to upload a doc file to a MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, blob, clob

I am currently experimenting on my own, learning some JDBC and how to persist objects to a database. Right now I am trying to upload a Document to the database. 
I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/mysql/jdbc/PreparedStatement.setClob(ILjava/io/Reader;)V is abstract
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setClob(PreparedStatement.java)
    at dao.StudentDAO.uploadResume(StudentDAO.java:156)
    at controller.Test.main(Test.java:30)
```

Have no clue why this is happening, can someone help me see the error?
Here is some of my code:

```
// this is in my studentDAO class:

private static final String SQL_UPDATE_RESUME = 
        "UPDATE students
        SET resume = ? 
        WHERE socialSecNumber = ?";

public boolean uploadResume(Reader r) {
        PreparedStatement pst;
        //Reader file;

        try{
            pst = con.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL_UPDATE_RESUME);
            //file = r;
            pst.setClob(1, r);
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Error when uploading the resume: " + e);
        }
        finally{
            con.closeConnection();
        }
        return true;
    }

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    File file = new File("C:/Users/Carlos L/Desktop/Resume.docx");
    Reader r = null;
    try {
        r = new FileReader(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error when locating the file: "+ e);
    }
    sdao.uploadResume(r);
}
```

}

Comment: It's likely that you JDBC driver does not support CLOB.  Have look at [Adding Large Object Type Object to Database](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html), which creates a `Clob` object instead of a `Reader`

Comment: Yeah i substituted the driver, and it worked. The file is now uploaded to the DB now, however it is not legible, i am looking at it through php my admin, I am using XAMPP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`PreparedStatement.setClob(int parameterIndex, Reader reader)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setClob%28int,%20java.io.Reader%29) was adding in Java 6, and you're using the JDBC driver from before that.

Upgrade to a Java 6 compatible driver, and your code will work.

Comment: Yeah youre right, i downloaded the latest driver and it worked. Now when i upload this to the database(I am using XAMPP with php my admin) the contents of the column where I uploaded the document is unreadable, it is all full of nonsensical data.

Comment: That sounds like a different question. ;-)

Comment: Lol I dont think i can ask more questions today.